# How to get all form elements when the DOM is ready?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I want to get all form elements (input, textarea, etc.) to add a function to all of these elements on blur.

Since the DOM is not loaded yet, I get an undefined for most elements. I tried to add

```
$scope.$watch('$viewContentLoaded
```

but that didn't work because I don't use ngView and I don't need ngView.

It works when I add a delay on the timeout, but this is not the best solution because the loading may differ on different environments

I tried:

```
angular.element(document).ready
```

but this also didn't get the elements.

This is the code which works, but not the best solution:

```
$timeout(() => {
 const allFormElements = $element[0].querySelectorAll('input, textarea');
 const formElement= angular.element(allFormElements[0]);
 formElement.on('blur', function() {
   console.log('THis is blur');
 });
}, 500);
```

Is there a better solution instead of using timeout with a delay to fix this, without adding the function manually to all fields.

FYI: I'm using `ng-switch` and some `ng-if` statements to show specific input fields. Maybe this is the issue. But I don't know.

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using? The tag for AngularJS 1.x is `angularjs` while the tag for Angular 2+ is `angular`.

Comment: mistake, changed to the correct one only. angular js.

Comment: What is `this.$element[0]` and are you creating the form or form fields dynamically?

Comment: $element[0] returns the element like <input-component><div><input class="form-field" /></div></input-component>

Comment: @Can you need to provide a working code snippet for someone to at least check the code and help. your question is too vague and can't be answered

Comment: I already did, there is a working code with timeout. And the question is clear, otherwise there would be no possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> FYI: I'm using `ng-switch` and some `ng-if` statements to show specific input fields. Maybe this is the issue.

To add a function to all `<input>` elements, define it as a directive:

```
app.directive("input", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        link: postLink
    };
    function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.on('blur', function(ev) {
            console.log('THis is blur', ev.target);
        });
    }
});
```

Directives such as `ng-repeat`, `ng-switch`, `ng-view`, `ng-include` and `ng-if` all add elements to the DOM at various times. The AngularJS framework invokes the `postLink` function for directives when it adds such elements to the DOM.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: does this add the function directly to the input fields? how can I also link textareas to this directive?

Comment: Can I add the directive as a seperated file and include it like this way (doing this for controller and template):

controller: fieldController,
template: template